# how to solve - Getting OLE2 exception while opening .xls excel file using selenium+java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, ole, browser-automation

[image]

[image]

Hello All

```
Hey,it's omkaar as a software tester(Automation Selenium+Java).
```

There is a scinario of reading excel file using Automation (selenium+java)which having .xls (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet) file extension.
Now i am not able to read excel file due to the error/popup massege(Please have look attched screenshot) which is obsereved while opening that file manually.

Steps which i have followed to read excel file.

1. Created object of file class and give the refference of that perticular file.
2. Created workbook instance.
3. Created sheet, row and cell instance.
4. Used "for each loop" to iterate through each cell to get the data.
   (You can also go through attached code.)

here is my code.
public class WorkWithXLSFile extends BaseTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Omkar Shrotri\\Downloads\\Ticketdetails.xls");

        if (file.exists()) {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

            HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            DataFormatter formatter11 = new DataFormatter();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
                String excel_data = formatter11.formatCellValue(sheet1.getRow(2).getCell(i));
                // int s = i+1;
                String web_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td['" + i + "']")).getText();
                if (excel_data.equals(web_data)) {
                    System.out.println("Passed");
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception NotOLE2FileException) {
        System.out.print(NotOLE2FileException);
        // handle popup
        // try code
    }
    

}
```

}